# inline style height not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Really not sure what I'm missing here, but the height of the inline style just wont update.

Here is the code:

```
var rightSideHeight;
    var optionsHeight;

    $(".quickViewContent .selectboxit-container").live("click", function() {
        rightSideHeight = $(".quickViewPopup .product-details-page .overview").height();
        optionsHeight = $(this).find(".selectboxit-options").height();
        var newHeight = rightSideHeight + optionsHeight;

        $(".quickViewPopup.active .quickViewContent").css("height", newHeight + "px");
    });

    $("#product_childattribute_size_@(Model.Id)").bind({
        "close": function (ev, obj) {
            console.log("rightSideHeight = " + rightSideHeight);
            $(".quickViewContent").css("height", rightSideHeight + "px");
            // Tried
            //$(".quickViewContent").removeAttr("style").css("height", rightSideHeight + "px");
            //Tried
            //$(".quickViewContent").get(0).style.setProperty('height', rightSideHeight + 'px');
        }
    });
```

So when a button is clicked I adjust popup height which works fine `<div class="quickViewContent product-details-page" style="height: 653px;">`

In the bind handler I want to revert the style, I can confirm the bind works because it's logging the original height. But the inline style just won't update which I thought was strange as it seems so simple.

Console output `rightSideHeight = 365` so I expect `<div class="quickViewContent product-details-page" style="height: 365px;">`

Also there are no console errors.

Why won't it update ?
Thanks

Comment: Also I tried some solutions from googling, as you can see by the code commented out but could not find anything which worked

Comment: It looks like you're trying to remove the attribute, rather than setting it back to `rightSideHeight`

Comment: I think, you should use !important property

Comment: @TanBirDeveloper definitely not the issue. Machinegunning `!important` is a great way to get quickly un-maintainable CSS.

Comment: @everyone the code inside the bind function should be `$(".quickViewContent").css("height", rightSideHeight + "px");` I read that removing the style attribute might work but it didn't. Will update answer

Comment: Try to have a log `$(".quickViewContent").height()` right after setting it to see if you got the right height. I'm suspecting there some other place that changing it right.

Comment: Yep want to avoid using `!important` for argument sake just tried it and still didn't work. This is odd because I have done this type of thing before. i.e changing height back and forward

Comment: If I log `$(".quickViewPopup .product-details-page .overview").height()` I get 365

Comment: I meant this one, in your `bind` function `$(".quickViewContent").height()` not in click  event

Comment: @lthh89vt See my answer, figured it out. Thanks for help :)

Comment: @Our_Benefactors  See my answer, figured it out. Thanks for help :)

Comment: @TanBirDeveloper  See my answer, figured it out. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omg so I figured it out, basically it was because I was using the click event for the selectboxit button to set new height, but then using the close event for selectboxit to try and revert the height.
But because I was clicking on the button to close the dropdown, it was cancelling each other out. So the click event was cancelling the bind event.

Here is what I needed to do.

```
var rightSideHeight;
    var optionsHeight;

    $("#product_childattribute_size_@(Model.Id)").bind({
        "open": function (ev, obj) {
            rightSideHeight = $(".quickViewPopup .product-details-page .overview").height();
            optionsHeight = $(this).next().find(".selectboxit-options").height();
            var newHeight = rightSideHeight + optionsHeight;
            console.log("newHeight = " + newHeight);
            $(".quickViewPopup.active .quickViewContent").css("height", newHeight + "px");
        }
    });

    $("#product_childattribute_size_@(Model.Id)").bind({
        "close": function (ev, obj) {
            console.log("rightSideHeight = " + rightSideHeight);
            $(".quickViewContent").css("height", rightSideHeight + "px");
        }
    });
```

So basically use the open and close bind events, and set my heights using them. Doh sometimes this stuff drives me mad lol.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace your last line of code with the following and see if it works>

$(".quickViewContent").css("height", rightSideHeight + "px");

Answer (score 0):

Use your code like this and it will work

```
$("#someElement").css({'height': setHeight+"px !important" });
```